# iMovie: simple red filter

Tags: imovie

I'm not sure this is the best place to ask this question.

I'm trying to simply apply a simple "red tint effect" on a video with iMovie, any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

That's not really an answer : I just moved to Final Cut to make that effect, as it seems that iMove can't do it.